# Create Spring beans with dynamic property values

Tags: java, spring

I have the following immutable class (i.e. in separate library I can't change):

```
public class MyClass implements InitializingBean, BeanNameAware {
  private BeanA prop1;
  private BeanB prop2;

  public MyClass() {}

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
      // do smth with prop1 and prop2
  }
}
```

I need to create multiple different MyClass beans but with property values (prop1, prop2) that are generated in runtime.

How to implement that?

I tried to implement `FactoryBean<MyClass>`, but the method `FactoryBean#getObject` doesn't have parameters.

`BeanFactory#getBean` with arguments can't be used, because `MyClass` doesn't have constructor arguments for those properties (it's separate library).

Comment: Why not do the initialization logic in your afterPropertiesSet method? Does the object know enough about what the properties need to be after its creation?
What's your use case here?

Comment: How are prop1 and prop2 set at all, are you using a configuration file?

Comment: @Konrad MyClass is provided by separate library, I can't change it.

Comment: Create a configuration class with `@Bean` methods for different instances of `MyClass`.

Comment: @Turo There are setters for prop1 and prop2.

Comment: @M.Deinum Parameter objects are generated dynamically, in runtime.

Comment: Again just create an `@Bean` method to create them, those parameters aren't interesting here, just use the `Environment` to access them. What makes you think that an `@Bean` method needs to be static?

Comment: So if there are Setters (You should have shown them in the first place) you could just subclass MyClass and create the constructor you need

Comment: You can create  a `@bean` and qualifier them by `@ConditionalOnProperty` using any properties variable

Comment: @kolobok consider either wrapping the class or creating your own bean which maintans and manages its own collection of MyClass objects.

Answer (score -1):

you could use `javax.annotation.@PostContruct`

```java
@Component
public class MyClass {

    private BeanA prop1;
    private BeanB prop2;


    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomethingAfterInstanced() {
        prop1 = null;
        prop2 = new BeanB();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the annotation equivalent of `InitializingBean` and doesn't help solve the qustion.

Comment: @Dilermando Lima Sorry, forgot to mention that MyClass can't be changed - it's provided by separate lib.